# Torsion-free flat module over a discrete valuation ring is Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, modules, cohen-macaulay

Why a torsion-free flat module over a discrete valuation ring is Cohen-Macaulay?

Comment: Dear unknown, do you want your modules to be finitely generated? Then they will be free in this case.

Comment: @Akhil Mathew..yes i need it..why this is true?

Comment: Dear unknown, torsion free modules over any PID are free (this follows from the structure theorem of f.g. modules over PIDS).

Comment: @AkhilMathew Hi: Do you think you could turn that into an answer? Thanks!